# Помогите составить sql запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

На рисунке, сверху таблица которая у меня есть мне нужно сделать таблицу которая снизу. То есть нужно чтобы если в колонке **"Symbol"** i **"Nazwa"** одинаковые значения они соединялись в одну строку, а колонка **"Numer Docymenty"** соединялась через запятую так как там всегда разные значения, и соответственно остальные колонки сумировались если произошло соединение, такие как **"Count"**, **"Wart.Netto"** і тд.

[image: Tabls]

Answer (score 4):

Судя по вашей картинке, у вас несколько задач.

1. Сгруппировать по `Symbol, Nazwa`. Собственно `GROUP BY Symbol, Nazwa`
2. Заново пронумеровать поле id. Если вам не важны пропуски, то
   просто `MIN(id)`, иначе `ROW_NUMBER(`)
3. Сконкатенировать строки `Number Docymenty` через запятую. В `sql server` 
   нет встроенных агрегатных функций для этого. Тут либо
   использовать подзапрос с `FOR XML PATH('')`, либо написать собственную
   агрегатную функцию средствами `CLR`.
4. Для поля `Jm` непонятно что делать, если в группе есть разные
   значения. Если вам не важно, возьмите любое(`max` или `min` из группы)
5. Просуммировать оставшиеся числовые поля. Это обычный `SUM()`.

Что именно у вас не получается сделать самостоятельно?

**UPD:** Просмотрел ваш запрос, вам не обязательно для каждого из столбцов `Stan, Rezerwacja, Dostepne` делать свой подзапрос. Можно всё подсчитать в одном `OUTER APPLY`:

```
USE E_M_KOPIA 

SELECT 
--tw_Rodzaj as Rodzaj max(tw_Symbol) As Symbol , 
max(tw_PodstKodKresk) As EAN , 
max(tw_Nazwa) as Nazwa , 
max(tw_Pole3) As Localizacja , 
(select dok_NrPelny + ', ' 
FROM dok__Dokument AS dd 
  LEFT JOIN dok_Pozycja AS dp ON dp.ob_DokHanId = dd.dok_Id 
  LEFT JOIN tw__Towar AS tt ON tt.tw_Id = dp.ob_TowId 
  WHERE dd.dok_Id = [dbo].dok__Dokument.dok_Id For xml path ('') 
)as NymerDokymentu 
  -- Roma Vav 16 июл в 14:23 upvote тревога 
, SUM (ob_Ilosc* ob_znak) AS Ilosc , 
  OA.Stan, OA.Rezerwacja, OA.Dostepne 
--, adr_Nazwa [Kontrahent] 
FROM [dbo].dok__Dokument -- Roma Vav 16 июл в 14:24
  INNER JOIN [dbo].dok_Pozycja ON dok_Id = ob_DokHanId 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].tw__Towar ON ob_TowId = tw_Id 
  LEFT JOIN kh__Kontrahent ON dok__Dokument.dok_PlatnikId=kh__Kontrahent.kh_Id 
  LEFT JOIN adr__Ewid ON kh_Id=adr_IdObiektu AND adr_TypAdresu=1 
  OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
      SUM(st_Stan)  AS Stan,
      SUM(st_StanRez) AS Rezerwacja,
      SUM(st_Stan - st_StanRez) AS Dostepne
    FROM [dbo].tw_stan 
    WHERE st_TowId = ob_TowId 
    GROUP BY st_TowId    
  )OA
WHERE ( (dok_Status in (7)) and (dok_typ in (16)) ) 
GROUP BY tw_Symbol,tw_Id,dok_Id,ob_TowId,ob_Id 
ORDER BY Symbol -- Roma Vav 16 июл в 14:24
```

Comment: USE E_M_KOPIA
SELECT  
 --tw_Rodzaj as Rodzaj
  max(tw_Symbol) As Symbol
, max(tw_PodstKodKresk) As EAN
, max(tw_Nazwa) as Nazwa
, max(tw_Pole3) As Localizacja

, (select dok_NrPelny + ', '
   FROM dok__Dokument AS dd
   LEFT JOIN dok_Pozycja AS dp
            ON dp.ob_DokHanId = dd.dok_Id
LEFT JOIN tw__Towar AS tt
         ON tt.tw_Id = dp.ob_TowId
   WHERE dd.dok_Id = [dbo].dok__Dokument.dok_Id 
For xml path ('')
)as NymerDokymentu

Comment: , SUM (ob_Ilosc* ob_znak) AS Ilosc
, ( SELECT SUM(st_Stan) FROM [dbo].tw_stan WHERE st_TowId = ob_TowId   GROUP BY st_TowId ) AS Stan   
, ( SELECT SUM(st_StanRez) FROM [dbo].tw_stan WHERE st_TowId = ob_TowId   GROUP BY st_TowId ) AS Rezerwacja   
, ( SELECT SUM(st_Stan - st_StanRez) FROM [dbo].tw_stan WHERE st_TowId = ob_TowId   GROUP BY st_TowId ) AS Dostepne   
--, adr_Nazwa [Kontrahent]
FROM [dbo].dok__Dokument

Comment: INNER JOIN [dbo].dok_Pozycja ON dok_Id = ob_DokHanId 
INNER JOIN [dbo].tw__Towar ON ob_TowId = tw_Id 
LEFT JOIN kh__Kontrahent ON dok__Dokument.dok_PlatnikId=kh__Kontrahent.kh_Id
LEFT JOIN adr__Ewid ON kh_Id=adr_IdObiektu AND adr_TypAdresu=1
WHERE (
(dok_Status in (7))                                         
and 
(dok_typ in (16))
) 
GROUP BY tw_Symbol,tw_Id,dok_Id,ob_TowId,ob_Id
ORDER BY Symbol

Comment: Не получается столбец "NymerDokymentu" не хочет соединять
[Вот что получается тут](https://pp.vk.me/c630916/v630916099/3c7bf/J62SPK6STH8.jpg)
А должно было соединить поля с одинаковым названием и символом

Comment: @RomaVav, добавьте ваш запрос в вопрос